# What is the difference between "Can ever" and "Could ever"

Tags: grammar, differences, british-english, can-could

Im just wondering what's differences between can and could. For example in this sentence.

- Do you think we can ever get there?
- Do you think we could ever get there?

I know that "could" is better but why? I've found some examples with " we can ever" too.

Comment: This is not about _can_ and _could_. Both of the sentences are questions, and questions are negative triggers. Hence _ever_ is grammatical; but if you make statements out of them, neither _could_ nor _can_ will work because _ever_ is an NPI. And how do you know that _could_ is better? Who says?

Comment: If "could" is supposed to be better, "Do you think we will ever be able to get there?" and "Do you think that it will ever be possible for us to get there?" would be the "better" ways of saying it. (I'm not actually saying they're better, I'm saying "could" really is no better than "can") Also, if you look at the differences between the two sentences I just wrote, I feel they illustrate the difference between "can" and "could" as you have given in your examples.

Comment: *Can* can mean *capable of*, while *could* can mean *do you think we will*. They two words can have specific different meanings, so neither is objectively better than the other without specific context.